# Use an http right frame instead of https on Login page

Tags: https, frame

I wish to use an http right frame instead of https for my login page.

However, it shows me, unable to do so as the website is http.

Is there a way to add our right frame on the login page?

Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't : it's blocked by the policy blocking active mixed content.

The https tells the visitor that his data is protected, if you put an http iframe, the browser can't assure the protection any more.

More informations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent